# SQL query to select all fields where creation date is more than 30 minutes old

Tags: sql

I have a table with some example columns below:

```
id       creationdate                 name
1        2012-08-09 14:14:22.225      ken
2        2012-08-09 13:11:20.212      john
```

I want to get all rows where `creationdate` is older than 30 min. from now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to make sure the creation date value is LESS than now minus 30, not greater. The lower the value of a datetime, the older it is.

```
SELECT
        Id,
        creationdate,
        name
    FROM TableName
    WHERE creationdate < DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, alternatively you could use '*' instead of listing columns if that works for your environment.  If you are dealing with UTC then use GETUTCDATE().

```
SELECT
    Id,
    creationdate,
    name
FROM TableName
WHERE creationdate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this gets rows with a `creationDate` _younger_ than 30 minutes in the past.  It's also considered very poor form to use `SELECT *`, for a number of potential reasons (especially relating to schema changes).  Good point about UTC, though.